# Does PHP's upload progress feature actually works?

Tags: php, file-upload, nginx

The problem is php 5.4's upload progress feature doesn't seem to work. NO matter what I do, the session variable isn't populated.

- The session.upload-progress variables are populated and set.
- file_uploads enabled
- upload_max_filesize set to 2000M
- post_max_size set to 2000M
- upload_tmp_dir writable
- the hidden variable in the form is set, its before any input elements and its name is: `ini_get("session.upload_progress.name")`

So far no success under Debian squeeze with dotdeb php 5.4.14 and apache2 with php5 module.

I've also checked the apc rfc1867 hook. Just doesn't work. Same with uploadprogress extension. Any ideas?

Examples used

for uploadprogress:
http://www.ultramegatech.com/2010/10/create-an-upload-progress-bar-with-php-and-jquery/

for apc:
http://blog.famillecollet.com/post/2011/01/12/File-upload-progress-in-PHP-with-APC

for php 5.4:
https://github.com/chemicaloliver/PHP-5.4-Upload-Progress-Example

php 5.4 inline (after the upload started, just calling the same file from another tab...):

upload.php:

```
<?
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION[ ini_get("session.upload_progress.name") . "123"]);

?>

<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>" value="123" />
 <input type="file" name="file1" />
 <input type="file" name="file2" />
 <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Answer (score 2):

Hell, nginx was the culprit. If its used as a proxy, it first stores the whole upload and when the whole file arrived, sends it to Apache or whatever else server you use. Hence no upload progress.

Comment: You should check with Nginx configuration I can imagine there is some configuration which allows to control that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

nginx 1.7.11 now has an options to turn off upload buffering:

Feature: the "proxy_request_buffering", "fastcgi_request_buffering",
       "scgi_request_buffering", and "uwsgi_request_buffering" directives.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_request_buffering
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_request_buffering

and with this options upload progress while now work with it !